# MySQL count usage of list of phrases in text field

Tags: mysql

Looking for a MySQL query that will enable me to count the usage of a list of phrases that may within a text column.

For example;

```
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field              | Type                | Null | Key | Default | 
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+
| smilie_id          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | 
| smilie_text        | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |
```

... and ...

```
+-------------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+-------+
| Field             | Type                                  | Null | Key | Default 
+-------------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+-------+
| post_id           | int(10) unsigned                      | NO   | PRI | NULL    
| message           | mediumtext                            | NO   |     | NULL
```

I want to count how many times smilie_text appears within message.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you maybe show some rows of what data is inside message and smilie_text. It is a but unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: smilie: 13, :barefoot: | 14, :cautious: | 17, :love:
message: 102364, This is my text post message with emoji :barefoot:

Therefore, inspect all rows in message_tbl.message to see how often any of smilie_tbl.smilie_text is used.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT  CAST((
                CHAR_LENGTH('smilie_text This is the smilie_text search text ssmilie_text') -
               CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('smilie_text This is the smilie_text search text ssmilie_text','smilie_text',''))
            ) / CHAR_LENGTH('smilie_text') AS UNSIGNED );
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT  CAST((
    ->                 CHAR_LENGTH('smilie_text This is the smilie_text search text ssmilie_text') -
    ->                CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('smilie_text This is the smilie_text search text ssmilie_text','smilie_text',''))
    ->             ) / CHAR_LENGTH('smilie_text') AS UNSIGNED ) as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      3 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the smilie table will contains meany records with smilie_text values. Thus, I think it would need to be a subquery of some sort.